# How to write a categorization accuracy loss function for keras (deep learning library)?

Tags: keras

How to write a categorization accuracy loss function for keras (deep learning library)?

Categorization accuracy loss is the percentage of predictions that are wrong, i.e. #wrong/#data points.

Is it possible to write a custom loss function for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Although Keras allows you to use custom loss function, I am not convinced anymore that using accuracy as loss makes sense. First, the network's last layer will typically be soft-max, so that you obtain a vector of class probabilities rather than the single most likely class. Second, I fear that there will be issues with gradient computation due to lack of smoothness of accuracy.

**OLD POST**

Keras offers you the possibility to use custom loss functions. To get the accuracy loss, you can take inspiration from the [examples](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/objectives.py) that are already implemented. For binary classification, I would suggest the following implementation

```
def mean_accuracy_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(K.sign(y_true - y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

Comment: it is multiclass, that is why i am having problems. I cant just take difference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will update my post, as I think there is an issue with the softmax layer.